# how can we increase or decrese the size of div on btn click in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how can we increase or decrese the size of div on btn click in asp.net?

```
 //stylesheet

      <style>div { width:50px; height:70px; float:left; margin:5px;
            background:rgb(255,140,0); }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    //div content
    <body>
      <div></div>
    </body>
    //script which m using for clicking

      <script>$("div").one('click', function () {
          $(this).height(30);
        });</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Doesn't work?  Error?

Comment: its wrking,on click its changing the size bt again its nt coming to its actual size after clicking...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Change height of Div on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616823/jquery-change-height-of-div-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [animate from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

This was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616823/jquery-change-height-of-div-on-button-click) a little while ago and he had a fiddle which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/JJh9z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You question is mismatch with what you have done in your code.

It mention that you need to **increase or decrease the size of div on btn click** . But your code is to `div` click event.
Also I think this is `Jquery` which you will need to include libraries

Edit your code to something like this

```
$("#ButtonId").click(function() {
  $('#DivID').height(30) ;  
});
```

**Update**

If you need to change back to the previous size on same click.. you have to use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: its changing the size,bt once its changed den again its nt coming to its actual size after clicking...